# Search row for matching partial strings then concatenate strings in new column

Tags: excel, excel-formula, concatenation, textjoin, multiple-matches

Apologies if this is something really obvious but egads it's driving me crazy and I can't find a non-array/helper box answer.

[image: Excel table]

I want to search cells D2 and E2 for matching numbers, and then concatenate these (using TEXTJOIN?) for each row in cell F2 (and then copy the formula down the column). So for eg I can see that D2 and E2 share unit 2, and cells D4 and E4 both have units 1 and 2 - so I'd like F4 to show "1,2". I want it to search for any and *all* numbers that match across both columns and return this in F as a comma-delimited concatenated string. Any help gratefully received.

Comment: You can use [`FILTERXML()`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) tricks to retrieve duplicates. For example: `=TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(D2&","&E2,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[following::*=.]"))`.

Comment: Do you have Windows and Office 365? (A combination of TEXTJOIN, FILTER, FILTERXML, and COUNTIF would accomplish that)

Comment: hyu~.. really need to know what the `//s[following::*=.]` does there..

Comment: Cool didn't know you could filter out duplicates that way in `FILTERXML`

Comment: Thanks so much for your replies. I tried copying and pasting but am getting a #VALUE! error and no idea how to resolve it - I'd not encountered FILTERXML before. Would it matter that cells D2 and E2 contain formulae, i.e don't simply contain the text 1,2,17 etc etc?

Comment: I also found this page on extracting substrings from Excel https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml in case it's helpful for anyone who ends up at this question - off to scour it now.

Comment: What is your version of Excel? 2019? 365? Depending on your version you'd need to array-enter the formula. Also, if no duplicates are found, the formula will return an `#VALUE` error. Note that it doesn't matter that the values are the result of formulae.

Comment: Thank you - I'm using Office 365 on Windows 10; it's returning an error when I paste it into F2, but should be picking up unit 2 as a duplicate across D2 and E2. I'll try to add an updated screengrab in case there's something I'm missing (highly likely).

Comment: It works fine for me. Can you confirm you actually need to use the comma to seperate parameters in a formula? Some countries locale setting use the semi-colon. E.g.: `=TEXTJOIN(",";;FILTERXML(".......`

Comment: I've got TEXTJOIN working with comma delimiters elsewhere in the workbook so I guess it's not that. Thank you for trying though!

Comment: It's hard to troubleshoot something that works on my end without the data, but are there any characters other than space, comma or numbers in those cells? Invisible characters like tab, newline or non-break spaces?

Comment: Weirdly it has now started working - maybe the old switch it off and switch it off again did the trick! One more question - where it doesn't find a match it's returning #Value! - is there a way to change this to "None" or just have the cell blank?

Comment: Yes, wrap the whole thin in `IFERROR()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments you can use `FILTERXML()` to retrieve the correct data:

```
=IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(D2&","&E2,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[following::*=.]")),"None")
```

For tips & tricks on how to use `FILTERXML()`, please see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61837696/9758194) post here on SO.